# Wordpress: Limit numer of posts per page + exclude category

Tags: wordpress

On my home page I have restricted the number of recent posts displayed using query_posts('posts_per_page=2')

I would like to also exclude a category but can't figure out how to integrate the two modifications to the loop.

Here's my original code:

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=2'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>

   <div class="date">Posted <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></div>
   <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
   <?php the_content('Continue Reading →'); ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>
```

I've tried following a few different tutorials but can't get them to work.  I'm sure this is my own lack of understanding, so any clear instructions or modifications to the code above will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `cat=-#` syntax in your query:

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=2&cat=-1');
```

**UPDATED** to show how to manually handle it in your loop:

```
<?php 
  query_posts('order=ASC'); 
  $count = 0;
  while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    $categories = get_the_category();
    if (!in_category('1')) { // category to skip
       $count++;
?>
   <div class="date">Posted <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></div>
   <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
   <?php the_content('Continue Reading →'); ?>

<?php
       if ($count == 2) break;
     }
  }
  wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: where # is the ID of your category

Comment: @Matt H That's it!  Just wasn't sure how to combine the two.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: Well...it does work, but now I'm finding all my posts are displayed in reverse order, meaning the oldest posts are first rather than the most recent posts.  When I remove the cat=-# syntax the posts are properly displayed once again. And interestingly enough, this problem is only showing up on the remote server.  All posts are in the proper order in my local development environment. Thoughts?

Comment: You can force ordering, e.g. `&order=ASC` or `&order=DESC` in the query. I don't know why it would be different - maybe a general setting in the admin panel.

Comment: `&order=ASC` does reverse the order, but oddly enough only when the `cat=-#` syntax is not included.  When the `cat=-#` syntax is in place it doesn't work anymore.  Weird!  I searched for a setting in the admin panel but am not seeing one.  Searched online as well but no luck.  Any other suggestions?  Thanks again!

Comment: Sounds like a Wordpress bug in their query syntax. Try using the reverse `cat` syntax, including only the categories you want displayed: `&cat=1,3,4`

Comment: Sure, that makes sense, but unfortunately it's not realistic to list all the categories I want to include.  This is a client's site and they will be adding categories here and there as they see fit.  I can't be keeping track of that.  Oh well.  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: In that case, I would get rid of the `posts_per_page=2` and manually count, then exclude the categories you don't want.

Comment: By "manually count" do you mean set the 'Blog pages show at most' option in the Setting>Reading admin panel?  I'm displaying 2 posts on the home page, and then 4 posts for all the other pages, so I don't think that's going to help me.  That's a design restriction, and hence the original use of the posts_per_page syntax.  By the way, I tried this... `query_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'order' => 'ASC', 'cat' => -23 ) );` ...just hoping a different take on it would knock it upside the head, but no luck.  Same results.  Tried both ASC and DESC, no difference.

Comment: @MattH Sorry, not following...can you give me an example of what you mean?  Thanks!

Comment: Oh oops sorry, I see it now.  Tried it out, and though it's offering me control over the the number of posts and the ASC/DESC order, it's not excluding the category.  I'm trying it on a category called "test" and so in your code where it says "category name to skip" I put "test".  Am I doing something wrong?  Thanks for hanging in there with me!

Comment: looks easier than I had - there's an in_category() function - updated my answer. Try that.

Comment: @MattH That did it!  You're a rock star.  Thanks a ton.  Interestingly enough, after some deeper research, I discovered this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/wordpress-posts-out-of-order-after-3-1-update Seems that an older version of MySQL is causing the reversal issue.  That explains why the post order was just fine on my local server, but reversed on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<?php
$specified_cat = new wp_query( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=10' );
while($specified_cat->have_posts()) : $specified_cat->the_post();
?>
<ul>
<li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<ul><li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: OP asking to exclude a category, you would have to make your category -3 in this case.